# Is there any difference between these two configuration options?

Tags: linux, kernel, iptables

Is there any actual difference between

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

and

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

?

I know that one is a firewall command while the other one is a kernel option. But:

1. I don't know whether `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0` is enforced by netfilter or by the kernel directly.
2. I don't know if there is any overhead associated with `iptables -P FORWARD DROP` compared to `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0`.
3. I couldn't find any reference clearly stating that these two options are actually identical in their effect.

In short, is there any actual difference between these two commands?

Comment: There might be some differences in ICMP messages generated. For example, TTL exceeded, fragmentation needed, etc. Not sure. I spent a few minutes trying to read the kernel code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you disable packet forwarding between interfaces the FORWARD chain is ignored at all. So, in connection to performance which is where your question is targeted it does not make any difference.

You can check it doing:

```
iptables -L -vnx
```

HTH